# is Cov(X, E(X|Y)) equal to VAR( E(X|Y) )??

Tags: probability, statistics

I am writing a code which uses the value of $Cov(X,E(X|Y))$. I thought it will be equal to $Var( E(X|Y) )$.
But my output seemed to be incorrect.

Please let me know whether my understanding is correct.

Let $Z = E(X|Y)$ which is basically $f(Y)$ and $$cov(X,Z) = E(XZ) - E(X)E(Z)$$

where $E(XZ) = E[ E(XZ|Y) ] = E [ E(f(Y)X|Y) ] = E[f(Y) E(X|Y) ] = E(Z^2)$
and $E(Z) = E(X)$

so then $Cov(X,Z) = E(Z^2) - E(Z) ^ 2$ which is $Var(Z)$

**EDIT: with CODE**

I am writing code in octave. I will simplify my code.
Say X, Y have joint distribution. 
I computed PDF for X and PDF for E(X|Y)

Joint PDF of X and Y

```
X|Y  -1    0   1
2    1/6  2/6  0
3    2/6   0   0
4     0    0  1/6
```

PDF of X

```
    1/2   2/6   1/6
  X  2     3     4
```

PDF of E(X|Y)

```
         2/6   1/2   1/6
Z=E[X/Y]  2    8/3    4
```

CODE

```
nSamples = 100000;

RX = [2 3 4];
PrX = [1/2 2/6 1/6];
X = randsample(RX,nSamples,true,PrX);

RZ = [2 8/3 4];
PrZ = [2/6 1/2 1/6];
Z = randsample(RZ,nSamples,true,PrZ);

disp(cov(X,Z))
disp(var(Z))
```

Comment: The analysis seems fine. May be include the code also for verification.

Comment: @stud_iisc thanks for confirming. I added code as you asked.